# How to adjust Google Sheets SQL query

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I'm working on a Google Sheet to organize some information. To get my formula working I created a small dataset and it works great as you can see in the image attached except that I have not been able to label the third column in the query.

The formula I used is:

```
=QUERY(A:C,"select A, sum(B), sum(C) where A is not null group by A order by sum(B) desc label sum(B) 'Original Value'",1)
```

In my actual worksheet I have the following query which is working:

```
={
  QUERY(
    Data!A3:K,
    "select A, sum(K) where A is not null group by A 
    order by sum(K) desc label sum(K) 'Initial Value'",
    1
  )
;
  {
    "TOTAL SHRINK",
    DOLLAR(SUM(Data!K:K),0)
  }
}
```

However if I try to add a third column like this below I just get a #Value error:

```
={
  QUERY(
    Data!A3:N,
    "select A, sum(K), sum(N) where A is not null group by A 
    order by sum(K) desc label sum(K) 'Initial Value'",
    1
  )
;
  {
    "TOTAL SHRINK",
    DOLLAR(SUM(Data!K:K),0)
  }
}
```

How can I create a solution that will give me the third header label and the third column?

Answer (score 1):

Because your `QUERY()` function will return 3 columns and you are stacking 2 columns in second formula. Add a extra empty column then stack two array. Try-

```
={QUERY( Data!A3:N,
"select A, sum(K), sum(N) where A is not null group by A order by sum(K) desc label sum(K) 'Initial Value'", 1 );
{"TOTAL SHRINK",DOLLAR(SUM(Data!K:K),0),""}}
```

You can use `VSTACK()`, `HSTACK()` instead of array notation {...} like-

```
=VSTACK(QUERY(Data!A3:N,
"select A, sum(K), sum(N) where A is not null group by A order by sum(K) desc label sum(K) 'Initial Value'",1),
HSTACK("TOTAL SHRINK",DOLLAR(SUM(Data!K:K),0),""))
```